# How can I run a <script> tag that I just inserted dynamically from a BHO

Tags: javascript, dom, bho

I'm completely new to developing IE extensions with Browser Helper Objects.

I managed to create a BHO that successfully inserts a script tag that references a javascript file in the head of the HTML page (see code below).

But the script tag just sits there in the DOM and the external javascript file is **not** executed.

Is there any way to tell the browser to run the external javascript file?

Thanks!

*Code Details:*
I call the following method on the OnDocumentComplete event:

```
void CHelloWorldBHO::InsertScriptTag(IDispatch* pDispDoc)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
// query for an HTML document.
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument3> pDocument3 = pDispDoc;
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDocument2 = pDispDoc;
if (pDocument2 != NULL && pDocument3 != NULL)
{
    // **********************   create our script tag Element  (pHtmlElem) ****************************
    IHTMLElement* pHtmlElem;
    CComVariant vAlert="http://www.gnpcb.org/esv/share/js/?action=getDailyVerse"; // example referencing external JS code
    CComVariant vJavascript="text/javascript";
    hr = pDocument2->createElement(_T("script"), &pHtmlElem); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pHtmlElem != NULL)
    {
        hr = pHtmlElem->setAttribute(_T("type"), vJavascript); 
        hr = pHtmlElem->setAttribute(_T("src"), vAlert);            
    }

    // **********************   insert Element  (pHtmlElem) in HTML Head ****************************
    // Get the head from the DOM.
    static const CComBSTR sbstrHead(L"head");
    CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> objects;
    hr = pDocument3->getElementsByTagName(sbstrHead, &objects);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && objects != NULL)
    {
        // Get the number of elements in the collection.
        long nElements = 0;
        hr = objects->get_length(&nElements);
        if (hr == S_OK && nElements > 0)
        {
            CComVariant svarItemIndex(0); // we will get the first element
            CComVariant svarEmpty;
            CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispElement;

            // Get the element out of the collection with index 0 (the first element, that is, the head)
            hr = objects->item(svarItemIndex, svarEmpty, &spdispElement);
            if (hr == S_OK && spdispElement != NULL)
            {
                CComQIPtr<IHTMLDOMNode, &IID_IHTMLDOMNode> spHeadNode = spdispElement; // query for DOM interfaces
                CComQIPtr<IHTMLDOMNode, &IID_IHTMLDOMNode> spNodeNew; 
                spNodeNew = pHtmlElem; 

                if (spHeadNode)
                {
                    spHeadNode->appendChild(spNodeNew, NULL); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of appendChild. And the syntax of what you need to exec is **very, very wierd**. But it accomplishes what you want -- namely, an external JavaScript is added to the DOM. Call this during OnDocumentComplete:

```
VARIANT vrt = {0};
CComQIPtr<IHTMLWindow2> win;
spHTMLDoc->get_parentWindow(&win);
CComBSTR bstrScript = L"var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var _js = document.createElement('script');  _js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); _js.setAttribute('id', 'bho_js'); _js.setAttribute('src', 'http://domain.com/script.js'); if(!document.getElementById('bho_js')) html_doc.appendChild(_js);";
CComBSTR bstrLanguage = L"javascript";
HRESULT hrexec = win->execScript(bstrScript,bstrLanguage, &vrt);
```

This will add `<script type="text/javascript" id="bho_js" src="http://domain.com/script.js"></script>` into the DOM HEAD.

Comment: Thanks Portman! 
Your code is much more elegant and compact ;) 
I have tested it and it indeed inserts the script in the DOM Head. 
However, I still have the same problem: your code does not actually RUN the external javascript [http://domain.com/script.js](http://domain.com/script.js) referenced by the script that it inserts.  
Is there a way to execute this external javascript?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "run". If `domain.com/script.js` contains a single line, `alert('foobar');`, then on every page you should see an alert. The JavaScript will "run" just by being on the page.

Comment: It's possible that JavaScript errors, either in your script *or on the page itself*, are preventing your script from being run. Open up the IE developer tools (F12) and look at the Console to see any JavaScript errors.

Comment: In my tests I use the simplest external js file I could find: [http://www.gnpcb.org/esv/share/js/?action=getDailyVerse](http://www.gnpcb.org/esv/share/js/?action=getDailyVerse). It executes a simple `document.write` with some text. I can see that the script has been correctly placed in the DOM, but it does NOT insert the text in the page. Also the IE developer tools reveal no JavaScript errors. In fact, if I create a dummy html page and insert the script tag that loads the external JavaScript file myself, it works fine (i.e., it inserts the text in the page). I am completely lost here...

Comment: What about if you change `document.write` to `alert`? Also, what pages are you trying this on? If it's a complex, styled page, just writing document.write into the DOM is probably not going to show up. You need to insert an absolutely positioned `div` with a high `z-index`. But first things first, try a JavaScript alert. If that doesn't work, you have a BHO problem. If that DOES work, but document.write DOES NOT, you have a DOM/CSS problem.

Comment: Yesss!!! I tested your code with the external javascript `http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna1.js`, which just shows an alert message and it worked! So, as you suggest the `document.write` didn't probably work because of a DOM/CSS problem. By the way, I tried the whole thing with the code I posted and it does not work. It only works with your code. Many thanks Portman!